# Accessing all classes from a .NET library file

Tags: c#, .net

I am working on windows application Project in .NET C#.
I have created a Library file namespace **xyz** with 3 classes in it  **class1 , class2**  and **class3**.

After adding the libaray reference, when I am using the **xyz** namespace in a WinForms application 
(`using XYZ;`),
then typing "**xyz**." is showing only one class **class1** in the list; the other 2 classes are not accessible.

Waht could be the problem?

Comment: Make sure all classes have `public` access modifier.

Comment: Please look at my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22273508/952310

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the classes are marked as `public`.

You can use the `public` access modifier like this:

```
public class class3
{
   // fields, properties, methods, etc.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

default access modifier for `class`  is `internal` which can not be accessed outside the `library`.

so make  your class access modifier as `public` explicitly as below:

```
public class MyClass
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I may strongly assume that the rest of the classes (`class2`, `class2`) within the `xyz` namespace are not declared with a `public` access-modifier and probably marked with `internal`, which is by **default** (**without specifying anything!**).

A `class` or any other member would not be accessed out of your assembly if they are not `public`.

**From MSDN:**

> The public keyword is an access modifier for types and type members.
>   Public access is the most permissive access level. There are no
>   restrictions on accessing public members.

Change it like that:

```
namespace xyz
{
    public class class2{....}

    public class class3{...}
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Two words: Access Modifier. Period.

Comment: This is the most concise way to state what is there in other replies. I do not see a point in your comment.

Comment: huh? Do you see a question or critique there? It is precise answer. I do not want to spoon feed. And please do not jump on he is a beginner band wagon now. Beginners are not treated very well here.